# PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

[PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart 205:7  FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8N5S.png)

Comment: update your firebase dependencies

Comment: Actually I'm Doing Flutter Unit Testing I don't think this Updating dependencies should work !! But will try ..

Comment: @JustinRoy did find a solution ?

Comment: Please ask your question in detail. What should we understand from an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I made the solution by :

1. Upgrading plugins & Flutter SDK
2. Cold Booting the emulator

The app properly runs now and that error is gone .

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution. Take a look into:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/test
There are 2 files. You need to copy mock.dart:

```
// Copyright 2021 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:firebase_analytics_platform_interface/firebase_analytics_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

typedef Callback = void Function(MethodCall call);

final List<MethodCall> methodCallLog = <MethodCall>[];

void setupFirebaseAnalyticsMocks([Callback? customHandlers]) {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setupFirebaseCoreMocks();

  MethodChannelFirebaseAnalytics.channel
  .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    methodCallLog.add(methodCall);
    switch (methodCall.method) {
      case 'Analytics#getAppInstanceId':
        return 'ABCD1234';

      default:
        return false;
    }
  });
}
```

And then in your test:

```
void main() {
  setupFirebaseAnalyticsMocks();

  FirebaseAnalytics? analytics;

  group('$FirebaseAnalytics', () {
    setUpAll(() async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
  analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
});

setUp(() async {
  methodCallLog.clear();
});

tearDown(methodCallLog.clear);

group('logEvent', () {
  test('reject events with reserved names', () async {
    expect(
      analytics!.logEvent(name: 'app_clear_data'),
      throwsArgumentError,
    );
  });

  test('reject events with reserved prefix', () async {
    expect(analytics!.logEvent(name: 'firebase_foo'), throwsArgumentError);
  });

  test('custom event with correct parameters', () async {
    await analytics!.logEvent(
      name: 'test-event',
      parameters: {'a': 'b'},
    );
    expect(
      methodCallLog,
      <Matcher>[
        isMethodCall(
          'Analytics#logEvent',
          arguments: {
            'eventName': 'test-event',
            'parameters': {'a': 'b'},
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  });
```

For me it works.